# $dateToString not outputting in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, command

For the following MongoDB (5.0.14) query, I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with the [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) command for a `projection`. The `failDateStr` value causes an error which results in the `projection` being completely ignored - can anyone see the issue here..? Thanks

```
{
    "failDateStr": { // does not work as expected
        "$let": {
            "vars": {
                "todayDate": {
                    "$date": "1701475200000" // actually visible as an output as as: {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1701475200000"}}
                }
            },
            "in": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "date": "$$todayDate",
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "successDateStr": { // works as expected
        "$dateToString": {
            "date": "$lastModified", // supposing this value to be a pre-existing field that is a date type 
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the root cause is. I am **guessing** that `$date` is a bson field object instead of a aggregation operator so it cannot be used in aggregation pipeline. You may want to use `$toDate` as an alternative to convert timestamp to date like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9nAb5Ydvsgy).

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/hfMVJlbusuA

Comment: You say "The failDateStr value causes an error" - what is the error?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of your collection?

Comment: @ray good workaround.

Comment: Have you considered using `$$NOW` instead of manually setting today's date?

Comment: @joe - yes but it seems everyone has assumed that this is for an `aggregation` but it's actually for a query `filter` on a [find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). I was illustrating here in a [project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to display the output. The point that I am making is that I don't believe `$$NOW` is accessible on anything but aggregations. Worth the shout though!

Comment: `$$NOW` also works in projection: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AGoPA2agbQj